# Constructing a regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

I need to construct a regex pattern that ensures that two substrings of the same string are equal.

i.e.

```
someString#MY_STRING#someString#MY_STRING#someString#
```

I have tried variants of the form:

```
+?#MY_STRING#+?#MY_STRING#+?#
```

But, how do I do this for dynamic **MY_STRING** values?

Comment: Use *capturing groups* and *backreferences*. I'm not sure I understand your pattern, though.

Comment: Which environment or language are you using? If the `MY_STRING` is dynamic, I assume it's in a variable? You'll need to dynamically define the regex which is dependent on the language/environment.

Comment: I had added C++ as a tag. It was removed. Yes, a variable, say: It is read as input and I need to regex a pattern with that input into a list.

Comment: There is no point adding a C++ tag unless you specify which C++ regex library you are using, e.g. `std::regex`, `boost::regex`, other ?

Comment: @PaulR That comment makes little sense to me. I agree that if OP has already chosen a regex lib they should mention it, but if you know that this is easily done with regex lib such-n-such, possibly OP could base his choice of library on the answers, no?

Comment: @funkwurm: well the original tags as specified by the OP were `regex`, `c++` and `nsregularexpression`, the latter being an Apple Objective C regex API for iOS/OS X, so it didn't seem that he really knew what platform, language or API he was using, which was why I reduced it to just `regex`. `c++` on its own doesn't really help much, but if that's definitely what he's now decided he's using then let it stand.

Comment: nsregularexpression tag was mistyped. I thought it to be regularexpression.

Comment: @thenoGk: for future reference you can hover over any tag and you'll get an explanation for the tag's intended purpose.

Comment: Noted. That was in a haste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[^#]*#([^#]*)#[^#]*#\1.*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/16

Comment: But, does this take into account cases like:
MY_STRING#MY_STRING#someString or
MY_STIRNG#someString#MY_STRING

Answer (score 0):

does this help? catch the group1

```
[^#]*#([^#]*)#
```

http://regex101.com/r/iO4uL8/1

if you just want to validate the string, the two "my_string" should occur in the string in certain format:

```
^[^#]*(#[^#]*#)[^#]+\1.*$
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one worked. Going by the timestamps, I vote for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out..with this Regular expression
((?:[a-z][a-z]+))

Comment: Thanks, yet to try this though.