# Checking a string for matching substrings

Tags: c++, regex, substring

I have a long sequence of segments separated by a delimiter say '-'. It is of the form:

```
I-am-logged-into-StackOverFlow-I-am-using-StackOverFlow-
I-am-reading-a-book-A-I-have-written-a-book-B-
```

The user specifies the segments that I have to compare.

Say, for string - 1, above: He inputs 5 and 9. Both contain **StackOverFlow**, so I return **true**.

For string - 2, segments 6, 12. But. they are different books A,B. So, I return **false**.

I have tried to do this using **std::regex**.

For all indices not entered by the user, I fill in those portions of a temporary string with
**([^-]+)-**, i.e. a string of one or more characters not containing a **-**, but ending with that.

For the two indices the user inputs,I face a problem. If I go with capturing groups and specify **([^-]+-)** in the first index and use a **\1** (or any nth capturing group) for the second index, the results are inconsistent. **Book**  matches **ANewBook** which is not what is expected. In some cases, **a-** matches with **not-**.

Then I match the sentences above, with this temp string.

**How do I check for equality - the characters from start to end, and the length of the substrings at the given indices**?

Also, I find this question similar, but some of the results there are not consistent. [Constructing a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379035/constructing-a-regular-expression)

PS: Considering the fact that it is easy to do a regex rather than extracting the segments at the given indices of a string and comparing the same, I would prefer the former. The number of string may run into hundreds.

Better solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (surely not the only one) could be to just use [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and extract two substrings for comparison

<sub>*(warning: the following code hasn't been extensively tested and might contain errors, it is intended as a concept idea for further refinement to suit your needs)*</sub>

```
bool match_positions(const std::string& str, int p1, int p2) {
    int wordNo = 1;
    size_t beg = 0, pos;
    std::string first, second;
    while ((pos = str.find('-', beg)) != std::string::npos ||
        (first.empty() && second.empty()) ) {
        if (wordNo == p1)
            first = str.substr(beg, pos - beg);
        if (wordNo == p2)
            second = str.substr(beg, pos - beg);
        beg = pos + 1;
        ++wordNo;
    }
    if (first.empty() || second.empty())
        return false;
    else
        if (!first.compare(second))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/ken1g3)</kbd>

Since this is (as I understood it) a "*find-the-substring-at-nth-delimiter*" problem, I wouldn't go for regex and leave those for more complex pattern matching tasks.

Comment: I am sorry. That is what I mean by extracting the segments. That is **find** the required '-' positions and extract the substring. Then compare the same.

Comment: @KutKV take a look at the example I posted, is that what you want? Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Okay, I'll keep this in mind. I am planning to construct a temp string as said above, use that as a regex, and then perform a regex_match on the list of strings that I have.

Comment: Yes, but to repeat this procedure for over a hundred strings? Is this optimal?

Comment: @KutKV In this case (single char separator) the complexity is O(n). If you could preprocess those strings you could have better options. (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Comment: Thanks for this. But, if I need to scale it to support three user indices, this has to be modified more than a regex (if it is possible). Right?

Comment: @KutKV you would simply add a "third" string and a condition in the code above (plus handle the comparison with three strings). I believe it would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: That is true, but what if the indices are known only at run time?

Comment: @KutKV I don't see the problem with that

Comment: Apologies. I mean, the number of indices.

Comment: @KutKV in that case you could also extend this code by checking for each index (while still not npos) whether that string was found or not. You could even short-circuit for more than 2 indices (i.e. if you have to check the condition for 9 indices and they must all match, it is sufficient that two indices don't match to abort and return false)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marco A. Regular expressions are overkill for this job.
A running variant with `istringstream`:

```c
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<limits>

bool equalSubStr(const std::string& str, int i1, int i2, char sep) {
    std::istringstream ss(str);
    std::string sub1, sub2;
    int i=1;
    if( i1 > i2 )
        std::swap(i1,i2);

    auto advance = [&ss,sep](int &i, int iLim) {
        for(; i!=iLim; i++) {
            if(!ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),sep))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    if( ( advance(i,i1)
            && std::getline(ss,sub1,sep)
            && advance(++i,i2)
            && std::getline(ss,sub2,sep) ) )
        return sub1 == sub2;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str1="I-am-logged-into-StackOverFlow-I-am-using-StackOverFlow-";

    int i1=5;
    int i2=9;

    if( equalSubStr(str1,5,9,'-') )
        std::cout << "\nSubstrings 5 and 9 are equal.";
    if( equalSubStr(str1,1,6,'-') )
        std::cout << "\nSubstrings 1 and 6 are equal.";
    if( !equalSubStr(str1,2,3,'-') )
        std::cout << "\nSubstrings 2 and 3 are not equal.";

    return 0;
}

/*
    Local Variables:
    compile-command: "g++ --std=c++11 test.cc -o ./test.exe && ./test.exe"
    End:
 */
```

Comment: Thanks. **istringstream** is something that I is new to me.